# Shnayim Vachamishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred fifty-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binyamin = 152 = בנימן

Answer (score 0):

1861 and 2013 were the last two times the fourth Thursday in November coincides (during the daylight hours) with *Chanuka*. ([Source and relevance.](http://jonathanmizrahi.blogspot.com/2013/01/hanukkah-and-thanksgiving-once-in.html)) Those are 152 years apart.

Answer (score 0):

152 Jews bought land in Gunnison Valley (in Utah) when it was divided into plots in the early 1900s. (Source: [Roger D. Hansen](http://www.waterhistory.org/histories/clarion/), citing [Robert Alan Goldberg](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1607811553).)